# CURL и https

Tags: curl, php, https

Такая проблема, когда делаю запрос с помощью curl на сервер https возвращается ошибка

```
SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

Если установить параметр

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
```

То приходит ответ:

```
405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.</h2>
  The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.
```

Может кто то знает как это побороть. через плагин хрома запрос нормально отправляется и приходит ответ без всяких сертификатов

Answer (score 2):

Твой сервер?
Возьми с него ключи и передавая их при CURL.

```
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CAINFO,'/path/1.cert');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSLCERT,'/path/2.pem');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSLKEY,'/path/3.key');
```

Пути прописать нужные и правильные, ну и отправить запрос

Comment: Неа, запрос идет на сторонний сервер. У меня сертификатов нет и ключей соответственно тоже. Со стороны этого сервера утверждают что на клиенте они не нужны

Comment: @oldy когда говорят про клиента подразумевают браузер, а т.к. ты коннектишься через curl то тебе нужно об этом подумать самому, как принять их сертификаты.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
```

Comment: неа, приходит "405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed."

Проблему решил с помощью file_get_content, с curl разобраться в чем проблема так и не получилось (

Comment: Попробуйте функцию [getInfo()][1]


  [1]: http://pastebin.com/NPNQfMcX